# Retrieving strings from textfields in a .fxml file when a button is clicked. (creating a login scene to switch scenes to home scene)

Tags: javafx

very new to programming. I am learning java and javaFX.

I have tried to make a login scene and a home scene and currently have a "login" button that invokes a method in the controller -loginButton()- that switches between the two scenes. The part I am unsure on is how to set up this method to retrieve the strings from the username and password text/password fields.
I am not interested just yet in setting this up with a database. what I want to go for is something like this (rubbish login details for the purpose of example, I would never actually use login info this bad):

```
public void loginButton(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    if(textFromLoginField=="admin"){
        if(textFromPasswordField=="Password123"){
            //run code to change scene
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to switch scene but I dont know how to get the login info (shown as textFromLoginField and textFromPasswordField in the example above.

How I am switching scenes

```
        Node node=(Node) actionEvent.getSource();
        Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("homeScene.fxml")),750,500));
        stage.show();
```

My FXML text:

```
VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="159.0" prefWidth="157.0" spacing="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: Black;" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="60.0" top="60.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                    </padding>
                    <children>
                        <Label text="LOGIN:" textFill="WHITE" />
                        <TextField fx:id="loginTextField" promptText="Username" />
                        <PasswordField fx:id="passwordTextField" promptText="Password" />
                        <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="137.0" spacing="10.0">
                            <children>
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" fx:id="loginbutton" onAction="#loginButton" style="-fx-background-color: Blue;" text="Login" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Button>
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" fx:id="helpbutton" onAction="#helpButton" style="-fx-background-color: Orange;" text="Help" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Button>
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

-Also, if I have used any technical vocab incorrectly please let me know. I am new to this. thanks

Comment: Assuming you have defined a `loginTextField` in the controller in the usual way, just do `if (loginTextField.getText().equals("admin"))` etc.

Comment: work through a basic tutorial on java .. that's what everyone new to anything needs to do ...

Answer (score 1):

"==" doesn't work with Strings. Use textFromLoginField.equals();. Check out the string functions.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing this out! I will bear this in mind when I find out how to get the string from the textField :)